# Adverbial Vs Noun clause

Tags: grammar

How does one interpret sentences having 'with the aim that' 'due to the fact that' etc which are taken as compound subordinating conjunction to introduce adverb clause? Though these can introduce adverb clause, one argument can be that the 'that clause'(acting as Noun clause) can be seen to be in apposition to Noun"aim/fact". Example- 
He did this with the aim that nobody should blame him.
It happened due to the fact that he was not happy. 
.Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. His failure was due to his idleness. (Simple sentence)

= He failed **because he was idle**. (Adverb clause of reason)

= His failure was due to *the fact* **that he was idle**. (Noun clause in apposition to the noun *'the fact'*.)

2. Despite his poverty, he was happy. (Simple sentence)

= He was happy **though he was poor**. (Adverb clause of contrast)

= He was happy despite *the fact* **that he was poor**. (Noun clause in apposition to the noun **the fact**.)

Adverbial meanings are expressed by the PP. (Preposition + NP).

Despite the fact (PP) ----> Prep. (Despite) + NP (the fact).

NP (the fact) ----> determiner (the) + Noun (fact)

"That he was poor" ---->> in apposition to the noun (fact) ----> Appositive Clause.

So, I think those are Appositive Nominal Clauses.

Comment: Thanks Sandip for your response. In that case how do we treat sentences having 'considering that'/seeing that/knowing that which are also used as compound subordinating subordinating conjunctions. Thanks